# CellForRowAtIndexPath not returning the same as didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UiTableView` containing Youtube Videos. The Youtube Videos are listed in the `TableViewCells` with the attributes title, author and link. The problem is when i try to return the value from the selected `indexPath` it returns another youtube video and not the one selected. why is it not returning the information from the selected video?

cellForRowAtIndexPath;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];



    video = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = video.title;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 12.0 ];
    cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@ views", video.author, FormatViewCount(video.viewcnt)];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    UIFont *myFont1 = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 10.0 ];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font  = myFont1;

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:video.thumb] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blankvideo"]];
    [cell.imageView.layer setBorderWidth:2];
    [cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

    return cell;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSLog(@"%@", video.title);
        NSLog(@"%@", video.author);
        NSLog(@"%@", video.videoid);
        NSLog(@"%d", thisObject.selectedRowNow);


}
```

Comment: selectedVideo = [items objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       //---------add one more line---------//
        video = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       //---------add one more line---------//
        NSLog(@"%@", video.title);
        NSLog(@"%@", video.author);
        NSLog(@"%@", video.videoid);
        NSLog(@"%d", thisObject.selectedRowNow);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write:

```
video = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

before `NSLog`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `video = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` you are just storing the last item that the tableview happens to have requested. No really point in storing it as an attribute of your class.

You can use a similar statement in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to retrieve the video that is actually selected:
`Video *video = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`